# Nesting SKActions not using wait duration

Tags: swift, duration, skaction

I am trying to do the follow on an SKSpriteNode:
Make it larger,
Move it to a new location,
Make it small again.

However, the code seems to all run at once the make it big and make it small cancel each other out.

Here is the code created in Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

var theirCard:SKSpriteNode
let CARDSHRINK_TIME = 5.0
let AICARDMOVE_SPEED = 2.5
let droppoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100,y:  100)

let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 480, height: 320))

let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 320))
sceneView.showsFPS = true
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

theirCard = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "card")
theirCard.name = "theircard"
theirCard.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width * 0.50, y: scene.size.height * 0.5)

scene.addChild(theirCard)

func getwait(makeBig big:Bool) -> SKAction {
    let ret = SKAction.wait(forDuration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
    var action:SKAction

    if big {
        action = SKAction.scale(to: 1.9, duration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
    }
    else {
        action = SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
    }
    theirCard.run(action, completion: { print("getwait \(big) done!") } )

    return ret
}



// We want to MAKE the node BIG, move it to the location, then make it SMALL again
let action1:SKAction = getwait(makeBig: true)
let action2:SKAction = SKAction.move(to: droppoint, duration: AICARDMOVE_SPEED)
let action3:SKAction = getwait(makeBig: false )
let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([action1, action2, action3])
theirCard.run(seq, completion: {
    print("animation complete!!!!")
})
```

I need to keep the getwait like it is because in the actual code its a method of the Card class (which is what the theirCard is actually).  I simplified it for testing in Playground

Update:

```
let action1 = SKAction.scale(to: 1.9, duration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
let action2:SKAction = SKAction.move(to: droppoint, duration: AICARDMOVE_SPEED)
let action3 = SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
```

Works as I would like, but would mean that I can not use the method from the Card class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the actions run all at once when you use `getwait(makeBig: true)` is because of the following line:

```
theirCard.run(action, completion: { print("getwait \(big) done!") } )
```

Whenever you invoke that function, you are immediately making a card run an action. So you can see why calling, in succession

```
getwait(makeBig: true)
getwait(makeBig: false)
```

will just have a net effect of the card scaling up and down at the **same** time.

I suggest you rewrite it as follows:

```
func getScaleAction(makeBig big:Bool) -> SKAction {
    return SKAction.scale(to: big? 1.9 : 1.0, duration: CARDSHRINK_TIME)
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
let scaleUp = getScaleAction(makeBig: true)
let move = SKAction.move(to: droppoint, duration: AICARDMOVE_SPEED)
let scaleDown = getScaleAction(makeBig: false)

theirCard.run(SKAction.sequence([scaleUp, move, scaleDown])) {
    print("done")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot.  
The reasoning behind my code is that I would call the getwait() which would scale the card right away, like you said.  
getwait() would return a wait action used by the sequence to wait for the actual scaling to complete.